# How to set text to integer that equals two different variables added together

Tags: java, integer

Here is my code:

```
public class TipCalculator extends Activity implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    EditText ba= null;
    TextView ta= null;
    TextView td= null;
    RadioButton t10= null;
    RadioButton t15= null;
    RadioButton t20= null;
    RadioGroup rg= null;
    DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("$####.00");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tip_calculator);
        ba=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.bill_amount);
        ta=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tip_amount);
        td=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Total_Dollars);
        t10=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.ten);
        t15=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.fifteen);
        t20=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.twenty);
        rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.tip_choices);
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rg, int i) {        
        if(i==t10.getId())
            ta.setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(ba.getText().toString())*.10));
        if(i==t15.getId())
            ta.setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(ba.getText().toString())*.15));
        if(i==t20.getId())
            ta.setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(ba.getText().toString())*.20));

        if(i==t10.getId())
            td.setText(( ba.getText().toString()+(ta.getText().toString())));
        if(i==t15.getId())
            td.setText("$");
        if(i==t20.getId())
            td.setText ( df.format(Double.parseDouble(ta.getText().toString()) +  Double.parseDouble(ba.getText().toString())));
    }
}
```

The part of the code that I'm getting my errors from is in the very last part. I am trying to set variable "td" to equal the two variables "ta" and "ba" but I either get an error or it concatenates the values of the variables instead please help!
thanks in advance!

Comment: as you can see I tried different ways for each of the different conditions in the if statements and none work. this is for the last 3 if statements by the way. The first 3 work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
td.setText(Double.toString(Double.valueOf(ba.getText().toString()) + Double.valueOf(ta.getText().toString())));
```